# If A1, A2, …, A10 are to speak and “either of A1, A2 should speak before A3, A4, A5”, how many orders are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, contest-math

The constraint on the order is:

> Either of A1, A2 should speak before A3, A4, A5.

---

A1, A2 > A3, A4, A5

I had a vague idea of doing it by selecting 5 members from 10. Out of 5, I selected 3 and permuted them and then selected 2 and permuted them. Then I permuted the remaining 5 members, which gives
$$
 {10 \choose 5} {5 \choose 3}\cdot 3! \cdot {2 \choose 2}\cdot2!\cdot5!
$$
But the answer isn’t this; rather, it is missing $5 \choose3$ and $2 \choose 2$.

But I believe that we are choosing specifically 2 and 3 people so these terms should be there.

Comment: Note that $2\choose2$ is just $1$, so it isn't really missing.

Comment: You cannot choose any $3$ spaces out of $5$. The first space out of $5$ has to be eithre $A1$ or $A2$. $2 \times 4!$ does the job.

Comment: Also $5!$ is missing for $A6$ to $A10$.

Comment: I think there are $(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)$ ways to arrange $A_6$ through $A_{10}$, then two ways to arrange $A_1,A_2$, then six ways to arrange $A_3,A_4,A_5$, making $(10)(9)(8)(7)(6)(2)(6)$ all up.

Comment: @GerryMyerson both of them do not have to be speaking before other $3$. Either of them or both can. So $2 \times  6$ will undercount.  You need $12 \times 4$.

Comment: @Math I take the problem statement to be ambiguous. You might have the correct interpretation. Anusha, would you like to clear this up?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can be wrong on my interpretation as well. It is ambiguous. What is your interpretation?

Comment: @Math I assume both have to speak before the other three.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I think Math Lover is correct. How else can you interpret the word “either”?

Comment: @GerryMyerson either is a correct word for it

Comment: @BrianDrake: Gerry Myerson’s interpretation isn’t possible, but the problem statement **is** ambiguous: *either* can be exclusive, in which case exactly one of $A1$ and $A2$ speaks before $A3,A4$, and $A5$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I am not convinced that “exactly one of $\{A1, A2\}$ speaks before $\{A3, A4, A5\}$” is a valid interpretation. But let’s say it is. Does that mean the other one has to speak *after* $\{A3, A4, A5\}$? For example, is $(A1, A3, A2, A4, A5)$ a valid order (ignoring $\{A6, \ldots, A10\}$ for now)? Or do we have to move $A2$ to the end, making it $(A1, A3, A4, A5, A2)$?

Comment: Assuming that we can take the OP’s answer and remove the two terms identified by the OP to get the “official” answer, it would seem that *both* of $\{A1, A2\}$ do have to speak before *any* of $\{A3, A4, A5\}$.

Comment: @Anusha Please edit this post and copy the entire question from wherever you found it, without changing any words. Also, did you find this question in a contest? Why is it tagged [contest-math]?

Comment: @BrianDrake: On that interpretation it means exactly what it says: exactly one of $A1$ and $A2$ speaks before all of $A3,A4$, and $A5$. There is no other restriction. On the inclusive interpretation it further allows both $A1$ and $A2$ to speak before all of $A3,A4$, and $A5$. We’re counting permutations of $[10]$ in which $1$ precedes all of $3,4$, and $5$ and $2$ does not, or $2$ precedes all of $3,4$, and $5$ and $1$ does not, or, on the inclusive interpretation (which is less likely on the basis of normal English usage), both $1$ and $2$ precede all of $3,4$, and $5$. Note that in all ...

Comment: ... cases the one that does not precede all of $3,4$, and $5$ may precede one or two of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering either of $A1$ or $A2$ speaks before $A3, A4, A5$ (which means, it can be both as well).

Selection of $5$ speaking positions out of $10 = {10 \choose 5}$

Permuting $A6$ to $A10$ in remaining $5$ positions $= 5!$

Now of the chosen $5$ positions, the first position cannot go to $A3, A4, A5$. So that leads to $2$ possibilities in the first place - $A1$ or $A2$.

Remaining $4$ places can be permuted in $4!$ ways.

So total number of ways $=  {10 \choose 5} \times 5! \times 4! \times 2$.

I think this is the right interpretation of the question but in cases -

i) If only one of them has to be speaking before $A3, A4, A5$ then

Number of ways $=  {10 \choose 5} \times 5! \times 3! \times 6$. This is because the second position has to be out of $A3, A4, A5$ ($3$ ways). So $2$ possibilities for first position and $3$ for the second. Rest $3$ can be permuted in $3!$ ways.

ii) If both of them have to be speaking before $A3, A4, A5$ then

Number of ways $=  {10 \choose 5} \times 5! \times 3! \times 2!$